# How can I convert a string into different characters?

Tags: vb.net

I have looked on the web and I cannot find anything that helps me, all I can find is changing the characters into ASCII or Hexadecimal. However I would like to do it a different way. For example, say the string that got passed in was `abcdef`, I would like to have a key which changes these characters into another string such as `qwpolz`. Is there an easier way than declaring each character in the alphabet to be another character like:

```
Dim sText As String = "Hello"
Dim sEncode As String = ""
Dim iLength As Integer
Dim i As Integer
iLength = Len(sText)

For i = 1 To iLength
    sEncode = sEncode ????
Next
    Return sEncode
```

And then have a very lengthy loop which checks for these loops? There must be a much simpler way. Can anybody help by pointing me in the right direction?

Edit: Why downvote? Seriously, it's a legitimate question. Instead of downvoting for no reason, just move onto another question.

Comment: How can I make it clearer?

Comment: Perhaps by adding a meaningful sample including code.

Comment: Okay I will do this now

Comment: @TimSchmelter str= otherstr would not work either. I do not know what the text passed in will be. At the moment sText = hello is just temporary. Just for testing purposes

Comment: You are asking people to write code for you. Just give it some thought. You can use two arrays of strings and can compare values with each other when encoding and decoding.

Comment: @savante This website is used for people with coding questions. It's not limited to just asking for plain text as help. Most of the time, people write sections of code for one another to help. I am new to this and have never done something like this before. So more explanation would help. Screw me right? How can I use two array of string to compare values? I don't know the text which will be passed in. Unless I create two arrays full of a-z and then the other way around. I don't see how that helps.

Comment: I was thinking like you one month ago, but plain text can help you much more than a boiler plate code. I showed you the way and you open google and search arrays. Read some documents and learn. Don't go with the easy way. Programming is all about the logic. If you get the logic, internet is full of information. Copy & paste will not teach you any logic or thinking as a programmer. Finally this site's logic is you try, investigate, research and ask people when you are stuck. That is not what you do.

Comment: Although you seem extremely 'elitist' right now. I appreciate the advice and will take it into account. My problem is that I understand the code but find it difficult to create myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds as if you want to modify a string by replacing each character with a different character according to a mapping table. An efficient approach is to  use a `Dictionary(Of Char, Char)`. But easier to write and maintain is something like this:

```
Shared ReadOnly replaceChars As String = "abcdef"
Shared ReadOnly withChars As String = "qwpolz"

Public Shared Function ReplaceAll(input As String) As String
    Dim newChars = From c In input
                   Let index = replaceChars.IndexOf(c)
                   Select If(index >= 0, withChars(index), c)
    Return String.Concat(newChars)
End Function
```

So the first string contains the chars that you want to replace and the second the replacement characters. Both strings must have the same length.

If you want to support case insensitivity:

```
Public Shared Function ReplaceAll(input As String, comparison As StringComparison) As String
    Dim newChars = From c In input
                   Let index = replaceChars.IndexOf(c.ToString(), comparison)
                   Select If(index >= 0, withChars(index), c)
    Return String.Concat(newChars)
End Function
```

Note that this is also a loop. There is no way to avoid some kind of loops if you want to replace multiple characters or strings.

Answer (score 1):

Well actually, this sounds like a [Caesar sipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)

[image]

```
Private Overloads Shared Function Encrypt(ByVal ch As Char, ByVal code As Integer) As Char
    If Not Char.IsLetter(ch) Then
        Return ch
    End If
    Dim offset As Char = IIf(Char.IsUpper(ch), "A", "a")
    Return CType((((ch + (code - offset)) Mod 26) + offset),Char)
End Function

Private Overloads Shared Function Encrypt(ByVal input As String, ByVal code As Integer) As String
    Return New String(input.ToCharArray.Select(() => {  }, Encrypt(ch, code)).ToArray)
End Function

Private Shared Function Decrypt(ByVal input As String, ByVal code As Integer) As String
    Return Encrypt(input, (26 - code))
End Function
```

Note that this assumes, that you use English alphabet. In general case where for example you have 'ä', 'ö', 'š', 'ž', 'ß', 'õ', 'ü' etc. this would not work. In that case it is simpler to just create a list/dictionary of your ordered alphabet and use it.

Example use:

```
encrypted = Encrypt(sText, 5)
decypted = Decrypt(encrypted, 5)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I did not know it had a name. I'm glad you understood what I meant.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't compile. @Andrew: You should accept it if it solves your requirement.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I haven't accepted it as my answer. But his answer has given me a clue on how to do the task at hand.

Comment: You can take a look at : http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher and any one of those implementation algorithms would work.